# Funktion returning strings, with specific lines in between

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I am trying to make a function, which is returning (and countinuing with more strings):

```
<ul>
<li>first string</li>
<li>second string</li>
</ul>
```

I have some troubles making the printing funktion work, so it is printing the content of the list1 combined with my funktion, on different lines. Here is what i have got:

```
#define the  html_list function
def html_list(input_list):
    for each in range(len(input_list)):
        input_list[each] = ('<li>' + input_list[each] + '</li>')
    return input_list

list1 = html_list(['string1', 'string2', 'string3'])

print('<ul>')
for element in list1:
    print(element.title)
print('</ul>')
```

It is returning:

```
<ul>
<built-in method title of str object at 0x102283b70>
<built-in method title of str object at 0x102283bb8>
<built-in method title of str object at 0x102283c00>
</ul>
```

Hope you can help me

Comment: It is function, not funktion. Funktion is german (and some other languages, which I don't know)

Comment: Thanks for your help - It is also danish ...

Comment: The code in your function `html_list` could be rewritten as `return ['<li>{}</li>'.format(each) for each in input_list]`. And then make sure to use `title()` to call the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `element.title()` to make it a function. You've just referenced `.title` hence your error.

When you change to `print(element.title())` your code works.

If you don't want capital L in `<Li>` then you can change your code to the following:

```
def html_list(input_list):
    for each in range(len(input_list)):
        input_list[each] = ('<li>' + input_list[each].title() + '</li>')
    return input_list

list1 = html_list(['string1', 'string2', 'string3'])

print('<ul>')
for element in list1:
    print(element)
print('</ul>')
```

Comment: Yes it will work, but it will replace `<li>` with `<Li>`.

Comment: Can you not use `.title()` in html_list() instead so it will only title the contents before being added in tags?

Comment: I still can't make a small L, because I am still using the title() function using your method Matthias

Comment: Don't use the original title() because that defeats the point. Move `.title()` to after `input_list[each]` in html_list loop and it works perfect.y I will update my answer so you can understand what I mean.

Comment: Now the code could be written as `return ['<li>{}</li>'.format(each.title()) for each in input_list]`.

Answer (score -1):

You should concatenate all the strings in the list before printing it.

Try this

```
print (''.join( for element in add))
```